# Auto-load dependent files in REPL

Tags: common-lisp, slime

I'm fairly new to Common Lisp, coming from Clojure, and am used to something like this:

```
(ns x.core
  (:require [x.util :as u]))
```

when I start a REPL and evaluate that file, `x.util` is automatically compiled and available to me in `x.core`.

In Common Lisp I'm trying to do something similar. In `main.lisp`:

```
(defpackage x.main
  (:use :x.util))

(in-package :x.main)

(comment
 (load "util.lisp"))
```

and in `util.lisp`:

```
(defpackage x.util
  (:use :common-lisp)
  (:export :foo))

(in-package :cl-blog.util)

(defun foo () 3)
```

the only way I know to have access to `foo` from `util` in `main` is to evaluate the form inside the `comment` macro (which I define similar to Clojure's comment, to ignore its body).

I have also tried this `x.asd` file:

```
(defsystem "x"
  :version "0.1.0"
  :author ""
  :license ""
  :components ((:module "src"
                        :components
                        ((:file "util")
                         (:file "main" :depends-on ("util")))))
  :description ""
  :in-order-to ((test-op (test-op "x/tests"))))
```

but that doesn't seem to help me with this problem.

Is there a simpler and more standard way to automatically load (or re-compile) `util.lisp` when I compile `main.lisp` in the REPL? What's the standard workflow for working with multiple files in the REPL?

Comment: what do you mean by 'compile main.lisp in the REPL' ? do you call `compile-file` or `load` (or both)?

Comment: @RainerJoswig Based on the docs (https://common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/Compilation.html#Compilation) I believe it does both? I'd ideally like to run Slime's `slime-compile-and-load-file` (`C-c c-k`) and not have it fail because `x.util` hadn't been loaded yet.

Comment: You really might describe a reproducible test case. Note, if you define a package (a namespace) and use another package, then the other package already needs to exist. Thus Lisp needs to see a package definition of that other package, before you can use it. Thus the usual thing is to load a needed stuff and then create a new package, possibly using an existing package.

Comment: Note that a package is nothing more than a namespace. It is not a module and it is not associated with files, etc. Files are organized by 'systems'. A system is one and more files and their relationship, making up a library or an application. Typically in a system there are also package definitions - but there is great freedom how to structure that. Typically one puts a package declaration into a file in a system and makes sure it is loaded early by that system.

Comment: I believe the current case as shown should be reproducible. I appreciate the distinction between packages and systems; what I'm specifically bumping up against is, when starting a new SLIME REPL, I have to explicitly load the individual dependent files. I want to find a way to do so automatically.

Comment: With ASDF: you load a system file and then do (asdf:load-system "foo"). Alternatively you don't need to load the system definition, but let ASDF find it: https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf/Configuring-ASDF-to-find-your-systems.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Manually this would be**:

File main.lisp

```
(eval-when (:load-toplevel :compile-toplevel :execute)
  (load (merge-pathnames "utils.lisp" *load-pathname*)))

(defpackage x.main
  (:use :x.util))

(in-package :x.main)

(foo)
```

file util.lisp

```
(defpackage x.util
  (:use :common-lisp)
  (:export :foo))

(in-package :x.util)

(defun foo () 3)
```

Then call `(load "/my/path/main.lisp")`.

More complex stuff would compile the file util.lisp if needed (if there is no compiled file or the lisp file would be newer)... and would then load the compiled code.

**Otherwise you would define a system with two files.**

main.lisp

```
(defpackage x.main
  (:use :x.util))

(in-package :x.main)
```

file util.lisp

```
(defpackage x.util
  (:use :common-lisp)
  (:export :foo))

(in-package :x.util)

(defun foo () 3)
```

Then define an ASDF system "my-system" (util.lisp is needed first and then main.lisp), load that system definition and call (asdf:load-system "my-system")... This would then load all files in the specified order/dependency.

Comment: Thank you for that answer. It's not clear to me yet how to get SLIME to do the necessary `load-system` ASDF magic, but the `eval-when` trick works if I substitute `*default-pathname-defaults*` for `*load-pathname*`, giving me a working solution when I `slime-compile-and-load-file`, which is good enough for now.

Answer (score 4):

The thing you show for Clojure only works when the required namespace is in a file on the classpath, in a file and directory with names that match the namespace by convention.  In order to manage the classpath (among other things), you use something like deps, boot, or leiningen.

In Common Lisp parlance, this is called *system definition*, and it works a bit differently.

The *de facto* standard tool for this is ASDF (Another System Definition Facility).  While in Clojure you first determine the classpath and then start the entire application at once with it, in Common Lisp, you first start the image and then load systems into it (a bit similar to pomegranate in Clojure).  Systems are defined in `.asd` files.  ASDF knows several standard locations where to look for such files, and you can add more both through a configuration file or even at runtime.

It is important to realize that systems and packages are completely orthogonal concepts for Common Lisp.  One system may define several packages, but things in one package might also be defined in different systems.  Also, packages have no relation to files.

So, in short, your `x.asd` is absolutely OK.  If you have in your system definition

```
:components ((:file "util")
             (:file "main")))
```

Then your `util.lisp` might be:

```
(defpackage #:x.util
  (:use #:cl))

(in-package #:x.util)

(defun foo ()
  'whatever)
```

And your `main.lisp`:

```
(defpackage #:x.main
  (:use #:cl))

(in-package #:x.main)

(defun bar ()
  (x.util:foo))
```

In order to load this system, you call `(asdf:load-system "x")` in the REPL.

You don't need to do anything then to enable referencing the other package.  The other package is already there, because ASDF loaded all the files declared as `components` in the system definition.

To recapitulate: instead of starting an image with a complete classpath definition and then loading a particular file to make Clojure load the dependencies first, recursively, you start a basic image and then completely load one or more defined systems in a correct order of dependency.

It is common in Common Lisp to *not* define one package per file.  Instead, a package is defined in a separate file, and other files then only have the `in-package` form at their top.

foo.asd:

```
(defsystem "foo"
  :serial t
  :components ((:file "package")
               (:file "utils)
               (:file "foo")))
```

package.lisp:

```
(in-package #:cl-user)

(defpackage #:foo
  (:use #:cl))
```

utils.lisp:

```
(in-package #:foo)

(defun frobnicate (bar)
  #| … |#)
```

foo.lisp:

```
(in-package #:foo)

(defun handle-vie (r)
  (wurble (frobnicate r)))
```

Many small libraries only have a single package, while bigger systems often have more and then also use some kind of pseudo-hierarchy (foo.bar, foo.baz).

There is also a newer addition to ASDF called *package inferred system*, which is in some ways more similar to the Clojure/Java mechanisms, but personally, I'm not convinced that this is a generally useful thing.